# Start new Activity when html button clicked in Cordova

Tags: java, javascript, android, cordova

I am trying to build Android Application with Cordova and Java.
I want to build intent that start a new Intent when button clicked in the HTML code.

This is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Demo Phonegap</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js">
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Hello Android</h2>
<button onclick="openNewActivity()">test</button>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my Java code:

```
public class MyActivity extends DroidGap {
    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.main);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }

    public void NewIntent()
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(this,HelpActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

How can I call the NewIntent() void from the html file without building plugin.

Thanks for answers
Haim.

EDIT:I using the phonegap for the GUI of my application.I want to call to another activity when button is clicked in the cordova html file.

Comment: Why do you want to call activity instead of .html file..??

Comment: on phonegap we r open html page not activity its phonegap not android

Comment: You need to create CordovaPlugin to use android Methods from JavaScript

Comment: Do you know how can I make this Plugin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know why you need to start an activity in DroidGap. But if you want to perform some native android code on Html's button click, you can use this approach.

You will have to use `JavascriptInterface` for WebView.

Example code snippet:

```
//in onCreate 
appView.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJSInterface(),
            "myJSInterface");
super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");


//JSInterface class
public class MyJSInterface {

    public MyJSInterface() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        Log.i(TAG, "constructor of jsinterface");
    }

    public void btnClick () {
        //do something
    }
}
```

And in your html:

```
<button onclick="callFunction()">test</button>
```

In your js:

```
function callFunction(){
    myJSInterface.btnClick();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! this is working.(I was need to load the url before add the JavascriptInterface).Thanks !!!!

Answer (score -2):

You'll need to create the button in java.
An example is below.

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id);
         button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 Intent i = new Intent(this,HelpActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);

             }
         });
     }
```

Comment: I am using button in cordova intent, not android button :(

Comment: You dont understand me. I have myActivity file that load html file with Cordova.I want to start another intent or do another things when button clicked in the Cordova intent.