# Start New Activity when Button is clicked in HTML in Cordova

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, phonegap-build

I need to open new activity and do other functions like display a Toast in native android java , when button in HTML is clicked. I found a similar question and solution with the problem I'm having, but unfortunately the answer doesn't help. [Start new Activity when html button clicked in Cordova](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25911025/start-new-activity-when-html-button-clicked-in-cordova)

Here is the log:

```
04-13 11:21:00.080: D/WebViewCallback(23907): onConsoleMessage
04-13 11:21:00.080: D/CordovaLog(23907): file:///android_asset/www/index.html: Line 13 : Uncaught ReferenceError: MyJSInterface is not defined
```

New Log using 'extends CordovaActivity':

```
04-14 10:21:33.544: W/ResourceType(18650): No package identifier when getting name for resource number 0x00000064
04-14 10:21:33.545: W/ResourceType(18650): No package identifier when getting name for resource number 0x00000064
04-14 10:21:34.229: W/ResourceType(18650): No package identifier when getting name for resource number 0x00000064
04-14 10:21:34.231: I/View(18650): Touch down dispatch to org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView{41cdc4d8 VFEDH.C. .F...... 0,0-720,1230 #64}, event = MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, id[0]=0, x[0]=52.92649, y[0]=183.81734, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=5511466, downTime=5511466, deviceId=4, source=0x1002 }
04-14 10:21:34.372: W/ResourceType(18650): No package identifier when getting name for resource number 0x00000064
04-14 10:21:34.372: I/View(18650): Touch up dispatch to org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView{41cdc4d8 VFEDH.C. .F...... 0,0-720,1230 #64}, event = MotionEvent { action=ACTION_UP, id[0]=0, x[0]=52.92649, y[0]=183.81734, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=5511610, downTime=5511466, deviceId=4, source=0x1002 }
```

And here is my Java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.cordova.*;

public class MainActivity extends CordovaActivity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.init();

        appView.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJSInterface(),
                "myJSInterface");
        // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
        loadUrl(launchUrl);
    }

  //JSInterface class
    public class MyJSInterface {

        public MyJSInterface() {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            Log.i(TAG, "constructor of jsinterface");
        }

        public void btnClick() {
            //do something
            Log.i(TAG, "HELLO");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "HELLO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

And in my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>PhoneGap</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
    <h1>Hello PhoneGap</h1>
    <button onclick="callFunction()">test</button>
 </body>
 <script>
function callFunction(){
    MyJSInterface.btnClick();
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: you are extending droidgap, that means you are using a very old version of cordova, you should use the latest

Comment: Hi, I have updated my java code and log..is this the latest version(extends Cordova Activity)...still not displaying the toast nor the Log on btnClick()

Comment: you have to put @JavascriptInterface over public void btnClick()

Comment: Already did..but it's not working...


@JavascriptInterface
        public void btnClick() {
            //do something
         Log.i(TAG, "HELLO");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "HELLO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

Comment: then try to create a plugin

Comment: also, do you have an idea why every time i run $ cordova build, my assets/www folder generates back from its original content and not in my updated and added html, js files?

Comment: because you have to work on the root www folder, not on the platforms/android/www folder

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at Cordova [plugins](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/guide_hybrid_plugins_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide), as it provides a standard way of accessing the native functionality of the device. It is preferable to baking in your custom way.

Closer to this topic, it might be that this [plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Toast-PhoneGap-Plugin) is exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks! Will look into it, but does it mean that plugin is a requirement for every event that I will make in native java from HTML?

Comment: It's not a requerimient, but is the recommended way of communicating js with java on cordova apps